# repetir un ciclo while en python luego de un ValueError

Tags: python

partiendo del siguiente codigo

```
def par_impar(): 
numero = int(input("introduce un numero: "))
while type(numero) == int:
    try:
         if numero % 2 == 0: 
            print(f"el numero {numero} es par ")
            break
         elif numero % 2 != 0: 
            print(f"el numero {numero} es impar ")
            break
    except ValueError: 
         print("Debes ingresar solo numeros enteros.")

 par_impar()
```

Como puedo hacer para que si se da el ValueError: Se vuelva a repetir el input y se evalue nuevamente la condición?

Probé esta otra solución:

```
def par_impar(): 
while(True):
    try:
        numero = int(input("introduce un numero: "))
        if numero % 2 == 0: 
            print(f"el numero {numero} es par ")
        elif numero % 2 != 0: 
            print(f"el numero {numero} es impar ")
        continue
    except: 
         print("Debes ingresar solo numeros enteros.")
par_impar()
```

EL problema es que ahora el bloque se repite siempre infinitamente. y si la respuesta es correcta, el bloque tiene que terminar. Solo debe continuar el while mientras la respuesta sea incorrecta.

Comment: En que linea tiene que suceder el error? En int(input...?

Comment: correcto, el error se produce en el int(input(

Comment: Entiendo! Gracias por la info. No estoy en un momento adecuado para dar una respuesta. Mañana (si nadie respondio antes) escribire una respuesta!

Comment: Por cierto, como notaste el codigo se ve mal en los comentarios. Cualquier informacion adicional que quieras agregar y sea muy extensa puedes agregarla editando la pregumta ;)

Comment: Continue es una forma de decirle al while "ignora el codigo que sigue y volve al while". Pon un break en su lugar, que rompe el bucle.

Comment: Por cierto, para evitar fallos extraños, me gusta poner la menor cantidad de codigo posible dentro del try-except.

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude resolver el ejercicio.

Dejo la respuesta para quien pueda servirle:

```
def par_impar(): 
    while(True):
         try:
             numero = int(input("introduce un numero: "))
             if numero % 2 == 0: 
                print(f"el numero {numero} es par ")
             elif numero % 2 != 0: 
                print(f"el numero {numero} es impar ")
             except: 
                print("Debes ingresar solo numeros enteros.")
             else: 
                 print("fin del programa.")
             break
par_impar()
```

aquí la clave se encuentra en utilizar un ELSE luego de la sentencia EXCEPT.
De este modo, se puede imprimir un mensaje de "fin del programa" y utilizar un BREAK para finalizar su ejecución.

Comment: Esta respuesta responde a *[...]"Como puedo hacer para que si se da el ValueError: Se vuelva a repetir el input y se evalue nuevamente la condición?"* ?

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Otra forma de hacerlo, si quisieras volver a ejecutar la función es llamar la misma función otra vez adentro de la excepción

Modifiqué la posición del `try` `except` para que evalúe si es entero o no al inicio

```
def par_impar():
  try:
    numero = int(input("introduce un numero: "))
  except ValueError: 
    print("Debes ingresar solo numeros enteros.")
    par_impar()
  while type(numero) == int:
    if numero % 2 == 0: 
      print(f"el numero {numero} es par ")
      break
    elif numero % 2 != 0: 
      print(f"el numero {numero} es impar ")
      break

par_impar()
```

Si deseas únicamente ejecutar la función cierto número de veces puedes agregar un contador en las excepciones para luego detener el programa

Comment: Siempre que sea posible, yo evito la recursion si se pueden usar bucles. No se si la recursion es una buena practica en este escenario. Pero dejando de lado eso, Python tiene un limite de recursion de 1000. Es decir, ocurrira un error si el usuario falla mas de 1000 veces.

Comment: Así es, gracias por agregar esa información

Comment: De nada! Me disculpo si ofendo...